# Is there a Low Quality / Headset audio mode and why to disable it?

Tags: headphones

My Bowers & Wilkins P5 came with 2 cables: One- for IOS and its control and another generic one without any control.

I made the terrible mistake of not pay attention and connected with the IOS cable. Immediately the Zenfone 3 entered what I can describe as a low quality mode. It looks like that Zenfone is trying to connect to a headset communication device instead of a hifi headfone. Immediately I recognized the mistake, changed to the generic cable and Zenfone recognized the headfone and quality came back to what is supposed to be.

However, after this incident Zenfone started to randomly goes back this "headset/low quality" mode. At first a simple re-boot would fix the problem. After that re-boot not worked anymore.
Only solution was to do factory restore. That worked well for a month but today my fone wake up back in "low quality mode".

Is there any other workaround to get out of this annoying mode?
Tested on B&W P5 and Grado SR125.

Any input is welcome....